# What does "DSF" mean in GDB (DSF)?

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging

I used GDB (DSF) in order to debug DLL builds in eclipse.

Can someone tell me what "DSF" means? I need a reference for my thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stands for "Debugger Services Framework".
See:
https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nftopic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dsf/intro/dsf_programming_intro.html?cp=12_0_5